# Use Connection variable in another function in jsp

Tags: jsp

I have one jsp file where I defined all the variables and want to use these variable in other jsp file in function body but when I am using Connection variable in function, it's saying variable not found. Can you please help me here?

a.jsp

```
Connection conn = null;
 conn = DriverManager.getConnection(Connecting_URL,DB_UserName,DB_Password);
```

b.jsp

```
        <%@include file="a.jsp" %>

        public static String user_exists (String email_id) throws Exception {

            String SEARCH_SQL_COUNT = "SELECT COUNT(*) USER_COUNT FROM V_USER_DATA";
            PreparedStatement st_fetch_product_count_1 = conn.prepareStatement(SEARCH_SQL_COUNT);
    -----
    -----    
return <string>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

a.jsp:

```
request.setAttribute("connection", conn)
```

b.jsp:

```
Connection conn = (Connection) request.getAttribute("connection")
```

PS:

1 - Is not good idea to use Scriptlet, use jsp taglib instead of that. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnake.html

2 - Is not good idea to use SQL on view Layer.